# on_call_tsx_state status code 180 Twilio Android

Tags: android, twilio, voip, pjsip

I am trying to make a call with Twilio using the Android SDK. Whenever I try the outgoing call, I get this error `on_call_tsx_state status code 180` in the log.

I tried looking it up online, but cannot find any lead. Does anyone have any idea what this error means?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an error, this is response code meaning that second party started ringing. Your application should generate audible ringback for user in this situation or use some other signaling method (I don't know if android version of pjsip takes care of it by default or requires adding some code). Alternatively there may be 183 code - meaning that early media session was started and second party would probably pass status signal as audio (it may be plain ringback but also some audio announcement as well).

Comment: Thanks. I will look further into it.